# Encoding with iso-8859-2

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

My code is:

```
var previousLines = new HashSet<string>();
File.WriteAllLines("D:\\textfile2.txt", 
                   File.ReadLines("textfile1.txt").Where(line => previousLines.Add(line)),
                   Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-2"));
```

I have two text files. In `textfile1.txt` I have words with letters like ł,ą,ę etc.
I want to rewrite all lines with no duplicates to the file `textfile2.txt`, but the encoding doesn't work as I expected. It eats some letters such as ł,ą,ę. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try `Encoding.UTF8` instead.

Comment: What encoding did you use to write `textfile1.txt`? By default, UTF-8 is used for reading. If you've used ISO-8859-2 when you wrote it, you'll need to specify it: `File.ReadLines("textfile1.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-2"))`

Comment: @cubrr I just copied a text from excel to a .txt file. Words that are used there are in Polish language. I just wanted to rewrite it with no duplicates, but even after no duplicates I had about 800 lines of text with mistakes... But Your answer works great! Thanks so much! It will save a lot of my time

Comment: You can remove duplicates in Excel as well.

Comment: That's not correct, use Encoding.Default to read the file.

Comment: Encoding.Default does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same encoding you used to write `textfile1.txt`. By default, UTF-8 is used for reading in `File.ReadLines`.

If you've used ISO-8859-2 when you wrote it, you'll need to specify it:

```
File.ReadLines("textfile1.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-2"))
```